# How to check if action result is partial view or view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to find out on client side what kind of action was executed? I just want to know if view is generated by `PartialView` method or `View` method.

I looked in headers but found nothing useful.
To achieve this I may add some headers into http response by overriding `PartialView` method.

```
protected override PartialViewResult PartialView(string viewName, object model)
{
    Response.AddHeader("is-partial", "of_course_this_is_partial");
    return base.PartialView(viewName, model);
}
```

But I want to know is there any built in solution in MVC 5? So I won't have to use a custom derived Controller class and use it everywhere.

Comment: you can check the content for the presence of the html tag, only emitted from ViewResults

Comment: @Slicksim This smells a little dirty ;) I don't want to parse the whole response for every request.

Comment: Dirty maybe, but given that you want to adjust the pipeline of mvc to add a header for partialviews, this way at least requires no modification to the header set in order to detect it.  Personally, I would just stop views from going out when it is an ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an action filter:

```
public class ResponseHeaderActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // use filterContext.Result to see whether it's a partial or not
        // filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader().. 
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }        
}
```

If you make this a global action filter, it's automatically executed and you don't have to inherit from a base controller or put it as an attribute on your controller:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ResponseHeaderActionFilter());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This way, the header is automatically added to each result.

Comment: lol, how did I I miss this. I have already an `ActionFilter` but didn't thought of it :(. By the way many thanks. This works super cool.

Comment: And I assume, MVC does not add any flag to find out what kind of `ActionResult` was sent. So I'm accepting this answer.